# How to display a column only in an edit mode GridView in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to display a column only in an edit mode

It's possible in aspnet c# GridView show one column only when the GridView is in Edit Template state ?

I have tried this code but in default.aspx page the GridView show one empty column in Template Field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Mono" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="---"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Y" Text="Y"> </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="N" Text="N"> </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Row Data Bound:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
                return;

            if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate) &&
            (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```